# YouTube Analytics API - Total views across channels for a content owner (network/partner)

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm trying to construct a YouTube Analytics API query to return the total views across multiple channels owned by a single content owner (a YouTube network).

My request looks like this: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?ids=contentOwner%3D%3D{MY_CONTENTOWNER_ID}&start-date=2000-01-01&end-date=2012-12-06&metrics=views&filters=claimedStatus%3D%3Dclaimed&key={MY_API_KEY}`

The query must include a filter, so I've included claimedStatus=claimed.

Two questions:

1. The value returned is off by a significant factor (almost 1/2) compared to the number reported for claimed videos in the YouTube Content Manager > Video Report.
2. How can I get at the view count for all videos, not just claimed videos?

I have the same question about querying total subscribers across channels.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Can you try `filters=uploaderType==self` instead of `filters=claimedStatus==claimed`? Does that give you metrics closer to what you'd expect?

Comment: Thanks for the response, Jeff. The number isn't any closer. It's different, but still off by a billion views (!).

Comment: Can you let me know what {MY_CONTENTOWNER_ID} is so that I could look into this further? Feel free to email me directly: jeffy at google com

Comment: I've followed up with the OP and it looks like this is a discrepancy between YouTube Analytics and another means of tabulating viewcount data. Both the YouTube Analytics web interface and the YouTube Analytics API seem to be offering matching data, though, so this isn't an API-specific issue.